# Bluetooth connection on Subaru

Tags: subaru, bluetooth, legacy

My bluetooth connection in my 2017 Subaru Legacy is off.  How do I reset it? I have tried to connect my Iphone, but I am unable to do so.

Comment: Is there a menu with some bluetooth controls?

Answer (score 4):

On page 5-69 of the [2017 Subaru Forester Owner's manual](https://cdn.subarunet.com/stis/doc/ownerManual/MSA5M1702C_STIS.pdf), there are instructions for enabling Bluetooth and connecting devices. Function no. 5 enables/disables Bluetooth.

[image: Bluetooth Settings]

I recommend procuring the exact manual for your vehicle from the [Subaru Vehicle Resources page](https://www.subaru.com/owners/vehicle-resources.html), which should contain a full description of the exact function of your vehicle.